# networkx: draw network as separating two types of nodes

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to draw a network with python's networkx.

I have two types of nodes and those types of nodes should be put separately. How do I separately put different type of nodes?

As an example, please see the below nodes.

[image]

I wish to separate red nodes (dog, cow, cat) from blue nodes (car, pen, paper, cup) like below pictures.

[image]

[image]

So, my question is **how `networkx` can draw these kind of networks which separate groups of nodes like the above images**?

As a reference, I paste the code which draw the first image.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
target_word_list = ["dog", "cow", "cat"] # represented by red nodes
attribute_word_list = ["car", "pen","paper", "cup"] # represented by blue nodes
word_list = target_word_list + attribute_word_list

for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
    G.add_node(i)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes
# draw nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=range(0, len(target_word_list)),
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=range(len(target_word_list), len(word_list)),
                       node_color='b',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)    
labels = {}
for idx, target_word in enumerate(target_word_list):
    labels[idx] = target_word
for idx, attribute_word in enumerate(attribute_word_list):
    labels[len(target_word_list)+idx] = attribute_word
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=14)

plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could manually shift the y coordinates of the nodes in one group up or down.
So, if you have your node coordinates in `pos`:

```
for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i] in attribute_word_list:
        pos[i][1] += 4
```

This will move the nodes in the second group up.

Your whole code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
target_word_list = ["dog", "cow", "cat"] # represented by red nodes
attribute_word_list = ["car", "pen","paper", "cup"] # represented by blue nodes
word_list = target_word_list + attribute_word_list

for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
    G.add_node(i)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) # positions for all nodes

# if node is in second group, move it up
for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i] in attribute_word_list:
        pos[i][1] += 4

# draw nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=range(0, len(target_word_list)),
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=range(len(target_word_list), len(word_list)),
                       node_color='b',
                       node_size=50, alpha=0.8)    
labels = {}
for idx, target_word in enumerate(target_word_list):
    labels[idx] = target_word
for idx, attribute_word in enumerate(attribute_word_list):
    labels[len(target_word_list)+idx] = attribute_word
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,labels,font_size=14)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]